# how to revert non-corrupted mssql database with stopat

Tags: sql-server, database, logging, restore

i have a good, working valid non-corrupted database in mssql that i want to revert to a point in time

how is that done?

the standard `RESTORE` command requires a full backup as a starting point, and then log backups thereafter.

i cant understand why this must be done from a backup. if my db is good and the logs are OK, why cant i just revert with a `STOPAT` from the live logs in the db?

one dba suggested that whenever i want to restore i should THEN make a log backup and then `RESTORE` with `STOPAT`. i believe it would work but sounds a little backwards

any better ideas?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can't restore from the LDF because older entries are removed as part of a log backup. Otherwise the DF will jut grow and grow.

There isn't enough information to "rewind" or "replay" everything.

So you use the backups you've taken which allow this.